# Installing python packages using pip

Tags: python, 17.04, pip

I am trying to install the pymemcache  on Ubuntu 17.04 using pip and I get the below error. The module gets installed without the -t option though. But, I want to install the module in a specific directory, so that I can package and upload to Cloud.

Could someone please help me out?

```
pip install -t /home/praveen/Code/AWS/Lambda/Memcached-Py pymemcache



Collecting pymemcache
    Using cached pymemcache-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six (from pymemcache)
    Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, pymemcache
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 360, in run
        prefix=options.prefix_path,
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
        **kwargs
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
        self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
        isolated=self.isolated,
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 247, in move_wheel_files
        prefix=prefix,
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/locations.py", line 153, in distutils_scheme
        i.finalize_options()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 289, in finalize_options
        raise DistutilsOptionError("can't combine user with prefix, "
DistutilsOptionError: can't combine user with prefix, exec_prefix/home, or install_(plat)base
```

Comment: I suspect your `pip`  is outdated. Try running `python -m pip install -t /home/praveen/Code/AWS/Lambda/Memcached-Py pymemcache`.

Comment: @edwinksl - I also thought it was something to do with the pip version, but the `pip -V` command returned me `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`. So, the pip is the latest version.

Comment: Ah okay. Looks like this is due to a conflict between the explicit `-t` option and the implicit  `--user` option that is present in Ubuntu's patched version of `pip`. See https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3826 and https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4390. To circumvent this, I would suggest using a virtualenv instead; I tried it and it works. I could write a more detailed answer if you would like to go down the path of using virtualenv.

Comment: Or you could try the `--system` option as mentioned in https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3826#issuecomment-232080694.

Comment: I tried it using virtualenv after posting here and it worked.

Comment: Sounds good, I can write something up later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is caused by a conflict between the explicit `-t` option and the implicit `--user` option that is present in Ubuntu's patched version of `pip`. This is described in `pip`'s GitHub repository at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3826 and https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4390.

To circumvent this, I would suggest using a virtualenv. The steps are as follows:

1. Install `virtualenv` if you haven't:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install virtualenv
   ```
2. Create and activate a virtualenv and upgrade `pip`:

   ```
   virtualenv venv
   source venv/bin/activate
   pip install -U pip
   ```
3. Install `pymemcache` in your specified directory using the `-t` option:

   ```
   pip install -t /home/praveen/Code/AWS/Lambda/Memcached-Py pymemcache
   ```